# Nested div floating alignment

Tags: html, css, css-float

having some fun trying to layout these nested divs and trying to figure out clears.  I'm trying to get my ad to the right of my content on www.ffldraftoptimizer.com but its showing up beneath my content.  Did so much testing and searching for a solution, really can't say what I have tried and what I haven't.  I've condensed the code and put in some comments as to how its basically laid out currently.  Hoping someone might be able to check out the site and help out.

```
//container:
    //div.MaxWidth
    //{
    //width:50%;
    //height:auto;
    //max-width:50%;
    //text-align:justify;
    //text-justify:inter-word;
    //}
    <div class="MaxWidth">
         //#left {float:left}   
        <div id="left">
        <div >
             <img src="images/optimizefront.jpg" class="floatLeft" />
                //content that wraps around the image as desired
        </div>
        </div>
        <div>
                //ad
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) on [JSfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net). Also see the [policy on just linking your project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: did my best to narrow it down and posted the code... not sure how a policy on "just linking my project applies"

Comment: Your literal remark *"Hoping someone might be able to check out the site and help out"* means the question will be unusable when you fixed the original site, making this question of no use to any future readers with similar issues.

Comment: it worked in ie and chrome, but still having problems in firefox as the left div spans the page and the right div is placed below it on the right side... any ideas? Its not of no use though because of the posted code

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the MaxWidth, and try this, this will separate it.

```
#left
{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
#right
{
width:50%;
float:right;
}

<div>
    <div id="left">
        <img src="......."/>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have been on you site in firefox, and i can't see the problem that you are describing

Comment: Ok well I tried it in FF 20.0.1 and FF 21 and it shows the ad at the bottom, but I'm really tired of messing with it, so its just gonna have to do. 2 out of 3 aint bad. Just letting future onlookers know the code may produce problems in FF. Thank you for the help